# Не запускается бот Discord

Tags: python, discord-api, discord.py

Хотел создать бота discord по документации

КОД:

```
    import discord

    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
      print('We have logged in as ')

    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
      if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

    client.run('МОЙ ТОКЕН')
```

ОШИБКА:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 256, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\kent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 220, in request     
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 UNAUTHORIZED (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/kent/Desktop/bot.py", line 18, in <module>
    client.run('AjcgZJsBn1KwB31_tv-02RSluNVlU-l1')
  File "C:\Users\kent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 640, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\kent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 621, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 584, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\kent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 442, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\kent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 260, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x0322A3D0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\kent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\kent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 715, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\kent\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 508, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: В traceback виден exception 401: Unauthorized токен не валидный или нет прав на его использование.

Comment: Вы спалили свой токен))) AjcgZJsBn1KwB31_tv-02RSluNVlU-l1 ; Вам на почту аккаунта должно прийти письмо о сбросе токена, замените на новый сгенерированный.

Answer (score 2):

```
import discord #библиотека
from discord.ext import commands 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='префикс') #это_префикс_бота

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is online')

#hello
@client.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{member} привет!')

client.run('токен бота')
```

извините что не объяснил

Answer (score 2):

1. Отсутствует аргумент `command_prefix` в discord.Client:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Prefix')
```

2. Невалидный токен бота скорее всего.

Answer (score 0):

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/') Замените на эту строку и и если вы захотите вызвать какую либо функцию (Например: функция test) пишите в чат /test и функция запускается.

Answer (score 0):

Ты не добавил токен бота, нажимаешь на кнопку получение токена, и вставляешь в скобки команды run, в кавычках но лучше сделай отдельную переменную [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также может быть, что ты не авторизовал бота на сервере это делается с помощью этой ссылки [https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?&client_id={id_client}&scope=bot&permissions=8](https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?&client_id=%7Bid_client%7D&scope=bot&permissions=8)
вместо **id client** вставь свое значение оно находится во вкладке главная информация